# How does a segue create the destination ViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

As the question suggests: how does a segue create the destination controller? To be specific, which method gets called? I want to init another ViewController from a nib when a segue creates him. How do I accomplish that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: `initWithCoder:` is called.

Longer answer ([from apple's docs on `UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

> If your app uses a storyboard to define a view controller and its
>   associated views, your app never initializes objects of that class
>   directly. Instead, view controllers are either instantiated by the
>   storyboard—either automatically by iOS when a segue is triggered or
>   programmatically when your app calls the storyboard object’s
>   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method. When instantiating a
>   view controller from a storyboard, iOS initializes the new view
>   controller by calling its initWithCoder: method instead. iOS
>   automatically sets the nibName property to a nib file stored inside
>   the storyboard.